# Unable to use a class instance in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to create a class to handle a few functions that will parse input and therefore I had to create an instance in `main()` like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class Triangle{

private:
    double a, b, c, h;

public:
    Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC): a(sideA), b(sideB), c(sideC){}

    double get_perimeter()
    {
        return a + b + c;
    }

    double get_area()
    {
        return (b*h)/2;
    }

    bool exists(double a, double b, double c)
    {
        return a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a;
    }
};

int main()
{
    double a, b, c, h;
    cin >> a >> b >> c >> h;

    Triangle t(a, b, c, h);

    if(!t.exists())
    {
        cout << "No such triangle!" << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    cout << t.get_perimeter() << endl;
    cout << t.get_area() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

However, I get the following error `triangle.cpp|37|error: no matching function for call to 'Triangle::exists()'|`

Comment: A bigger problem appears to be that you call the constructor with 4 args, but it only takes 3...

Comment: Shouldn't this be called `if(!t.exists(a,b,c))`?

Comment: `triangle.cpp|37|error: no matching function for call to 'Triangle::exists(double&, double&, double&)'|`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Member function exists is declared as having three parameters

```
bool exists(double a, double b, double c)
```

However you call it without arguments

```
if(!t.exists())
```

So the compiler is unable to find function exists declared without parameters.

You should define the function like

```
bool exists() const
{
    return a + b > c && a + c > b && b + c > a;
}
```

because it seems a, b, and c are data members of a class instance.

Also you declared constructor as having three parameters

```
Triangle(double sideA, double sideB, double sideC): /*...*/
```

However you call it with four arguments

```
Triangle t(a, b, c, h);
```

I think that the value of h should be calculated based on values of a, b, and c instead of  be entered.

Comment: How do I actually find the height by given a, b and c?

Comment: @dwvaxaz  If I am not mistaken then the area can be calculated based on all three sides of a triangle. SO in fact you need not h. Look a reference on geometry how to calculate a triangle area based on all three its sides.

Comment: Right, but problem persists on the other hand. I still can't get it to work even with parameters.

Comment: @dwvaxaz There is a formula of Heron (I do not know how correctly to write the name of this ancient mathematician). All you  need is to calculate the perimeter.

Comment: I don't mean the formula but the actual question.

Comment: @dwvaxaz  I showed you how the function and the constructor shall be declared.

Comment: @dwvaxaz Please reread one more my post and compare what is written  with your code.

Comment: @dwvaxaz Function exists has no parameters but you call it with arguments.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling it without parameter.

```
if(!t.exists())
```

However you have declaration as :-

```
bool exists(double a, double b, double c)
```

On similar lines your constructor call is not matching with its declaration...

Comment: Now I get `triangle.cpp|37|error: expected primary-expression before 'double'|`